# Method or source to quantitatively compare a Mercator projection to a Lambert Conic Conformal projection

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

There are many oyster boats where I live. The boaters are being fined for encroaching “supposedly” on off-limits oyster beds. The natural resource people are using information from the conic projection to determine the oyster boat’s location while the boaters are using the Mercator. The boaters are arguing they are getting no where near the oyster beds. Therefore, I need a method for determining the angular and/or linear discrepancies between the two maps.

Comment: You can use [proj4.js](http://proj4js.org/) to do conversion between projections.

Comment: @TomazicM is correct.  You could also plot the Mercator projection locations on a map using QGIS.  On the same map, plot the bounds in Lamert projection.